# What's the most reliable way to crash a Flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, crash

I need to add some code that will crash my Flex application if certain conditions are met. I need it to work whatever state the Flex application is in (maybe it's not fully initialized, maybe some components are still being loaded, etc.)

What is the most reliable way to accomplish that?

Comment: Is it guaranteed to crash the app? If I'm not mistaken, URLLoader throws an exception when there's an uncaught ioError but that doesn't crash the app, does it?

Comment: Why don't you just show modal popup window, preventing user to interact with your app?

Comment: URLLoader dispatches `IOErrorEvent` which is not the same as throwing an error.

Comment: -1 and a vote to close.  Why do you want to try to crash any app on purpose?  Tell us what your conditions are and why you want to do this.  I can guess that if you load up 100 YouTube videos and start playing them all at once it would probably crash the app.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, to be honest it's none of your business. I explained what I'm trying to do, and that's all you need to know to answer the question. Loading 100 YouTube videos is not what'd called a reliable method, since it might work on some computers, or Flash might delay the loading of some videos (I believe Flash has a limited number of audio channels among others).

Comment: @Laurent My YouTube video comment was snippy; sorry.  However, writing code for the sole purpose of crashing software on a person's computer is malignant, so I assume you either misstated  your intent or are trying to cause trouble.

Comment: Hooked Function Injection anyone...

This sounds like Evil is about to be done to a flex app or a loaded app. 

I can think of lots of times you want to cause a crash, but its usually so you can inspect mem and then hack, crack, pack or inject to something.

I agree with www.Flextras.com

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, Craig Mc, you are getting it completely wrong, I have absolutely no malicious intentions and - believe me - I'd rather not have this kind of code in my app. It's a necessity for this particular project and it's not done against regular users. Also I am trying to crash MY app, not any random Flex app, nor the user's computer or browser (an uncaught exception would only crash my app, nothing else). Maxim Kachurovskiy below got that right.

Comment: @Craig MC Then be sure to vote to close.  Laurent, An uncaught exception will not crash an app.  Maxim's instructions are instructions to abuse existing bugs in order to crash the Flash Player. That could, potentially affect other Flash Player apps or even the browser.  Your request is no different than trying to write .NET code to crash Windows, or Objective C code to crash OSX. If you want to make your app unusable by the user that is something completely different; and completely valid. But that isn't what you asked for.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, there's no reason to close this question, it's completely within the scope of SO. As for an **ActionScript exception** crashing the whole Flash plugin/ActiveX or the browser, I don't think you know what you're talking about. Maybe do some tests, and see if other running Flash apps indeed crash (they obviously won't). And by the way, my app is for Adobe AIR so your remark is even less relevant.

Comment: (Thought I agree that Maxim's solution might be a bit extreme. I think I'll go for a normal uncaught exception. Again I want to crash my own app only - if anything else crashes, it's not a good solution.)

Comment: @Laurent I posted an answer with some code which proves that throwing an uncaught exception is not the same as crashing the app.

Comment: +1 for Laurent & Maxim. This is very interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try one of [unresolved crash bugs](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20in%20%28%22ASC%22,%20ASL,%20FP%29%20AND%20issuetype%20=%20Bug%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open,%20%22In%20Progress%22,%20Reopened,%20Community,%20New,%20%22Internal%20Review%22,%20%22Under%20Investigation%22,%20%22Waiting%20on%20Info%22%29%20AND%20Reproducibility%20=%20%22Every%20Time%22%20AND%20Severity%20=%20%22Crash/Hang%22%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20DESC), e.g. [this one](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-3849):

```
public function TestVerify () { 
    try { 
        with (this) { 
            return; 
        } 
    } 
    catch (e) { 
        trace('catch'); 
    } 
    finally { 
        trace('finally'); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments are kind of dragging along; but I wanted to post some code to prove a point about uncaught exceptions and crashing the app.  So, here it is.

If you want to cause an exception, use the [throw command](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=11_Handling_errors_02.html) and the [Error class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html).  The uncaught exception will not crash the app.

Here is an example that you can copy and paste and run.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" applicationComplete="windowedapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function windowedapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var error : Error = new Error();
                throw error;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>



    <s:Button />
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

If you execute this app from Flash Builder, you'll see that you get a "standard" error pop up.  But, once you click dismiss you can still click the button and interact with the app.

Having an uncaught Exception is not the same as crashing the app; or preventing users from interacting with the app.

If you just want to prevent users from interacting with the app you should be able to do do something along the lines of `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.enabled == false;` .  But, in the comments you keep insisting that is not what you want to do.

Comment: Hehe I love that last sentence.